# Transforming a sentence creates an infinite loop - but how?

Tags: prolog, text-manipulation, failure-slice, non-termination

I can't figure out where this is going wrong. Please note that I am very new to Prolog and I'm sure I'm missing something - just no idea what that might be. Could anyone help me out please?

Thanks, here is my code:

```
printSentence([]).   
printSentence([W|[]]) :-
    write(W),
    write('.'),
    nl.  
printSentence([W|R]) :-
    write(W),
    write(' '),
    printSentence(R).

transform([], Result).  
transform([Word|Rest], Result) :-
    replace(Word, Replacement),
    append(Result, Replacement, NewResult),
    transform(Rest, NewResult).

replace(my, your).
replace(i, you).
replace(you, me).
replace(am, are).
replace(Word, Word).

test :-
    X = [you, are, my, only, hope],
    transform(X, Result),
    printSentence(Result).
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? What is the desired effect of the transform predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Notice you had a singleton in `transform([],Result)`. Also, append doesn't work in the way you tried to use it, but you were on the right track generally.

```
transform([], []).

transform([Word|Rest], [Replacement|RestOfResult]) :-
    replace(Word, Replacement),
    transform(Rest, RestOfResult).
```

Comment: Trying to get my head around having Replacement in the declaration.

Comment: @paranoid-android: consider: `maplist(replace, X, Result)`.  And there is still a serious bug in your program!

Answer (score 6):

@Junuxx' answer is one step to the solution ; there is also another problem in your program. But first step back: @Junuxx spotted the problem and fixed it. Nice. But how can *you* spot such a problem? Actually, you asked **»infinite loop – but how?«**

What is cool in Prolog is that you can often localize the looping program up to a very tiny fragment of the program. Such a fragment is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). That is: No more eye-sores reading lengthy programs!

Let's get back to your program. If you load it, you will get a message like:

```
Warning: /usager/SO/paranoid.pl:13:
    Singleton variables: [Result]
```

Which gives you already a hint on something most probably wrong. Alas, this is **not** your biggest concern for the moment. Your biggest problem is that the goal `test` loops!

## Localizing non-termination

So how can you with low effort realize what is actually looping?

**One way** would be to fire up a tracer, which will show you step-by-step how Prolog executes this program. However, the tracer will show you a lot of irrelevant detail. Detail, that you do not need to understand when programming in Prolog. Detail, that fills up your mind such that chances are that you will miss the actual problem completely. So unless you want to spend time on screens full with flickering lines, stay away from tracers.

**The other way** is to add goals `false` into your program. Remember, your program loops already, so such extra goals will not hurt you much. Why vandalize your program with these `false` goals that you never wanted to write in the first place? It's because these `false` goals will help you detect the culprit of non-termination in your program by hiding "irrelevant" parts. This is so, thanks to the following observation:

**If** a failure-slice (= your vandalized program) does not terminate **then** the original program does not terminate either.

In a sense, the failure-slice is a reason why your program does not terminate. Or to put it more strongly: As long as you do not change the visible part in a failure-slice ; that is, as long as you are only trying your luck by modifying parts that are not visible in the failure slice, the problem will persist! Guaranteed! That is not the nicest kind of guarantee but it is better than being blind.

Here is what I get as a failure slice. I removed `printSentence/1` because it is no longer used in the fragment.  And I added the definition of `append/3`. Some Prologs offer `append/3` as a built-in predicate that you cannot modify. In that case use another name, like `local_append/3` – just don't forget to replace all occurrences!

```
append([], Zs, Zs) :- false.
append([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :-
   append(Xs, Ys, Zs), false.

transform([], Result) :- false.
transform([Word|Rest], Result) :-
    replace(Word, Replacement),
    append(Result, Replacement, NewResult), false,
    transform(Rest, NewResult).

replace(my, your) :- false.
replace(i, you) :- false.
replace(you, me).
replace(am, are) :- false.
replace(Word, Word) :- false.

test :-
    X = [you, are, my, only, hope],
    transform(X, Result), false,
    printSentence(Result).
```

When I load this failure-slice, I get:

```
?- test.
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Which is a good indication that the program does not terminate. On my finite hardware it exhausts all resources instead. ((To be pedantic, this program might still terminate, it might only need too much resources. But remember: We have this **if** failure-slice loops, **then** the entire program loops. In any case, proving non-termination of the failure-slice will often be easier, since the fragment is shorter)).

Some observations: Originally, `transform/2` used to be recursive. Now, it no longer is. The only recursion left is within `append/3`. So I first look at the goal `append(Result, Replacement, NewResult)` and I try to figure out what the variables might be. The easiest is the 3rd argument: `NewResult` is the only occurrence in our fragment, we can thus replace it by `_`. The second argument's variable `Replacement` will always be `me`. And the first argument (here I have now to look at `test/0`) will be an uninstantiated variable. So we have to consider the goal `append(_, me, _)`.

Simply run `append(_, me, _), false` to see that this goal does not terminate! You can see this also by inspecting the failure-slice. Here is it, again:

```
append([], Zs, Zs) :- false.
append([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :-
   append(Xs, Ys, Zs), false.
```

Look at `Ys`: Nobody cares about it, it is just "handed over". Only the first and the third argument might guarantee termination!

For more see the tag [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

---

## Fine print

<sub>Certain restrictions apply! Void where prohibited! You can do above reasoning only with a pure, monotonic Prolog program. Actually, some benign side-effects as the ones you have in your program are OK too. As long as they do not affect the control-flow.</sub>

---

## The other problem

There is another problem with your program.  Run `printSentence([you]), false` to see it! Backtracking and side-effects do not flock together easily. For a beginner, the best is to avoid side-effects all together. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9744641/772868) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791028/772868) for an example, how to remove useless side-effects in programming problems.
Why not call `transform([you, are, my, only hope], Xs)` or `maplist(replace,[you, are, my only, hope], Xs)` directly? It lets you again concentrate on the relevant parts!