# PROLOG:How to exclude an option

Tags: prolog

I have this piece of code which suggests for a certain animal which other animals can  coexist to it under those circumstances:

```
suggest(X) :- bigAnimal(X),bigAnimal(Y),coexist(X,Y),write(Y),nl,fail.
```

This loops until fail.My issue is that it prints out also the variable **X**

[image]

How can I exclude it from the output, thx in adcavance.

Comment: Is `coexist/2` symmetric? In other words, do you have both `coexist(narty,nelmam).` and `coexist(nelmam,narty).` facts?

Comment: `writeln(Y)` is the same as `write(Y), nl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
suggest(X) :-
    bigAnimal(X), bigAnimal(Y), X \== Y, coexist(X,Y), write(Y), nl, fail.
```

Answer (score 3):

In your program you are mixing querying via the toplevel shell and performing side-effects with `write/1`. In this manner you will most probably miss a lot of what Prolog can offer you.

Instead, stick to pure side-effect free relations and let all writing be done by the toplevel.

Thus, instead of `suggest/1`, consider a new relation, say `biganimal_compatiblewith/2`.

```
biganimal_compatiblewith(X,Y) :-
   bigAnimal(X),
   bigAnimal(Y),
   coexist(X,Y),
   dif(X,Y).     % maybe

?- biganimal_compatiblewith(X,Y).
   X = melan, Y = narty 
;  X = melman, Y = nelman
;  ... .
```

Now, both `X` and `Y` are printed on the toplevel.  Think how useful this relation is compared to the original `suggest/1`. You can ask for one or the other, or you even can ask

```
?- biganimal_compatiblewith(X,X).
```

You can also reuse this relation, building more complex ones:

```
?- biganimal_compatiblewith(X,Y), burgervore(Y).
```

That is the essence of Prolog relations. You can spare out side effects for quite some time.

For another example how to avoid unnecessary side effects: [What are the pros and cons of using manual list iteration vs recursion through fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744641/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-manual-list-iteration-vs-recursion-through-f/9791028#9791028)

Answer (score 1):

When I have this piece of code:

```
bigAnimal(elephantas).
bigAnimal(kamilopardali).

coexist(elephantas,kamilopardali).
coexist(kamilopardali,elephantas).
/* coexist has to be symmetric */


suggest(X) :- bigAnimal(X),bigAnimal(Y),coexist(X,Y),write(Y),nl,fail.
```

The result is as expected.

```
2 ?- suggest(elephantas).
kamilopardali
false.
4 ?- suggest(kamilopardali).
elephantas
false.
```

You shouldn't end your code with `;` because that means `OR`. When I tried to compile that, I get an error. That's why I have to end my rule with a fullstop (`.`)